# Is there an equivalent to php.net for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, documentation, manual

I am looking for an equivalent to the php.net manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/) but for javaScript methods and syntax.

Is there a single site that lists out all the javaScript functions available in a clear and concise manner as php.net provides for the PHP language?

Comment: check out https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mozilla Developer Central](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference) with its [Core JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference) is a good resource. But as JavaScript is object-oriented, the reference is object-oriented too and there is no overview of all functions/methods.

And if you want to did deeper into how JavaScript works, I recommend to read the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), the standardized language dialects like JavaScript and JScript are derived from.

Answer (score 5):

[Mozilla's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference) is pretty good, although it's structured in a different way than [php.net](http://php.net/). That page lists classes and global functions, at least, but it doesn't touch upon the DOM. (Which, technically speaking, isn't part of JavaScript of course.)

Comment: The DOM references are elsewhere on MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when you search for JS/HTML/CSS first link you would get is W3Schools. But why not to use it http://www.w3fools.com/ this will give you a nice answer.

Prefer [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/projects/javascript/)

Comment: W3Schools is really very poor quality. It was the best of a bad bunch in the 90s, but it isn't something to recommend today.

Comment: @Quentin I agree totally Thanks .... updating answer ...